# Renaming dynamic URL with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a PHP project and I want to rename the URL of some specific pages which are dynamic.

for example, I have this URL.

https://example.com/@dynamic name

I want to change it to.

https://example.com/artists/@dynamic name/portfolio

how can I do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

This .htaccess file will redirect

https://example.com/@dynamic_folder 
to 
https://example.com/artists/@dynamic_folder/portfolio

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dynamic_folder/(.*)$ artists/dynamic_folder/portfolio/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !dynamic_folder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/artists/dynamic_folder/portfolio/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Code explanation**

- Options +FollowSymLinks is an Apache directive, prerequisite for mod_rewrite.
- RewriteEngine On enables mod_rewrite.
- RewriteRule defines a particular rule.
- The first string of characters after RewriteRule defines what the original URL looks like.
- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} shows which URLs we do and don't want to run through the rewrite.

  - In this case, we want to match example.com.
  - ! means "not." We don't want to rewrite a URL that already includes folder1, because then it would keep getting folder1 added, and it would become an infinitely long URL.
- [NC] matches both upper- and lower-case versions of the URL.
- The second string after RewriteRule defines the new URL. This is in
  relation to the document root (html) directory. / means the html
  directory itself, and subfolders can also be specified.

  - $1 at the end matches the part in parentheses () from the first string. Basically,
    this makes sure that sub-pages get redirected to the same sub-page
    and not the main page. Leave it out to redirect to the main page.
- [R=301,L] - this performs a 301 redirect and also stops any later rewrite rules from affecting this URL (a good idea to add after the last rule). It's on the same line as
  RewriteRule, at the end.

Comment: you mention "dynamic_folder" on this line 
`RewriteRule ^dynamic_folder/(.*)$ artists/dynamic_folder/portfolio/$1 [R=301,L]` but in my case, this is a dynamic name and coming from the database according to page. so i cannot statically write this in .htaccess.

Comment: Then you can't do it. Because .htaccess file cannot be dynamic, that's a static/constant thing on server.